# Override height attribute and disable it

Tags: css

I have style that looks like this

```
.label-bold-pre-wrap {
    font-weight: bold !important;
    white-space: pre-wrap !important;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
    border-color: #c2c3c4;
    background: transparent repeat-x;
    background-image: url(../reindeer/table/img/header-bg-light.png);
}
```

But it slightly breaks the markup in some places due to `height` attribute. If I disable `height` property (do it in browser) it displays label just fine.

I need this style in other places, where it doesn't break anything. But in my certain case I need basically the same style, but without `height` attribute.

How to achieve that?

Comment: apply `height: unset;`. It sets the height back to it inherited value or if that is not available to the initial value.

Comment: You mean you want to keep the height on `.label-bold-pre-wrap`, because that class is used in multiple places, you only want to disable/unset the height in a specific one? Then you start by finding something that makes your “certain case” discernible from all the other cases - like an ancestor with a certain class or of a certain type, so that you can use that to create a more specific selector.

Comment: an extra class or a specific selector matching only one of your labels could do . but your bit of CSS without your HTML structure won't help much. Can you clarify the question and show an example where you have that label where height should not be applied ?

Comment: well as a workaround I created the same style without `height` attribute but I wanted some better approach if any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your css code

```
 .label-bold-pre-wrap {
    font-weight: bold !important;
    white-space: pre-wrap !important;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
    border-color: #c2c3c4;
    background: transparent repeat-x;
    background-image: url(../reindeer/table/img/header-bg-light.png);
}
    .other{
        height:auto;
    }
```

your html code

```
<div class="label-bold-pre-wrap">hloo</div>
<div class="label-bold-pre-wrap other">hloo</div>
```

Comment: yes it will work's because `label-bold-pre-wrap` is just set height and 'other' will change fix height to auto . if we set !important to `label-bold-pre-wrap` then `other will not work`

Answer (score 2):

Please try `Height: auto;` or `height: initial;`. It will overwrite your `height: 20px`

Comment: i do not believe this answers the question **But it slightly breaks the markup in some places  .....  I need this style in other places, where it doesn't break anything. But in my certain case I need basically the same style, but without height attribute.** the op needs to reset height for some element, not all of them :(

Comment: Just use 'label-bold-pre-wrap' class where need the same CSS and overwrite the height property with the unique selector.